# Adding column to a document library automatically in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, document-library, column, metadata

For a document library in SharePoint 2013, there will be 3 columns by default **i.e., Name, Modified and Modified by**. But I want an extra new column with a `hyperlink` to be added along with these 3 columns to a document library in SharePoint 2013. Is it possible? 
Is any code available for that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatically'?  You mean every new library created by the user should be with an extra column?

Comment: Yes.. That's what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a document library with the required number of columns and save the library as the template which can be reused by the users.  It will be available under 'Add an App'

1. Create a document library
2. Create/add columns
3. Under List Setting ==> Save list as template

More information is available [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)